# Users are redirected to My Account page if not logged in. Still redirected if logged in. Cached redirect?

Tags: php, function, redirect, caching, woocommerce

I added code to my functions.php that redirect users to My Account page if they try to visit any Woocommerce page.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_redirect_non_logged_to_login_access');
function wc_redirect_non_logged_to_login_access() {
```

`if ( !is_user_logged_in() && ( is_woocommerce() || is_shop() || is_cart() || is_checkout() ) ) {
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id')) );
    exit();
}}`

Everything worked fine - Users tried to visit Shop page, they did get a redirect to My Account page, after logging in they can access Shop.

***The problem started when I migrated to WP Engine.*** Now if a user visits Shop page, gets redirected to My Account, logs in and tries to visit Shop - he still gets redirected to My Account.

I contacted WP Engine and they added the below listed Woocommerce cache exclusions:

^/cart/
^/my-account/
^/checkout/
^/product-category/
^/product/
^/wc-api/
^/resetpassword/
product
wc-api=
woocommerce_cart_hash
woocommerce_items_in_cart
Wp_woocommerce_session_
wp-resetpass-

But the problem still persists.

Domain going through Cloudflare, so I exempted this path from caching. So I made page rule for /my-account/ page - Caching Level - Bypass, but the problem still persists.
Here are my page rules: https://ibb.co/28k84cM

After that, I did a little experiment and added a test site (https://residenceineu.wpengine.com/)  that is hosted with WP Engine. DNS is not going thru Cloudflare. Everything is on WP Engine - hosting and domain. In result, the problem did not disappear. **Therefore I think that WP Engine is in fault.**

Here is a screenshot of responsive headers info.: https://ibb.co/dMwQ8t5

By, the way when I disable browser cache in browser inspect settings the problem disappears.

Interesting point is that when the code is added to functions.php and **if firstly we visit My Account page (without clicking on Shop page) and then log in, and after logging in we visit Shop page, we can access it - no redirects, everything works fine.
The problem starts when we firstly visit Shop page, afterwards are redirected to My Account, and after logging in we try to visit Shop page again.**

So summarizing this - when we visit the My Account page and then go to the Shop page - no cached/redirects, everything works fine. If we do this other way around by visiting Shop page - getting redirected to My Account - logging in - try to access Sho page = getting redirected to My Account again, even if logged in.
So taking all this into account **it seems that whole redirect process is cached if we visit Shop page first without logging in.**

I am in contact with WP Engine support, but we still have no solution.

Any ideas? Maybe after migration to WP Engine, they automatically did rewrite something in wp-config.php or .htaccess file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP Engine specifically excluded /shop/ path from caching. This solved the issue.